# Collect Tracking Code userInfo email shows undefined

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, website-integration, tracking, userinfo

I am trying to use the Collect Tracking Code to get the user ID that viewed any page on my website, y have this code

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window._etmc = window._etmc || [];
.
.
.
// after ajax function returns userid to use
window.datalayer_data.userID = '';
        if (data.success) {
            window.datalayer_data.userID=data.userid;
            if (typeof _etmc !== 'undefined' && typeof _etmc.push === 'function') {
                _etmc.push(["setOrgId", "XXXXXXXXXX"]);
                _etmc.push(["trackPageView", { "item": window.datalayer_data.postId }]);
                _etmc.push(["setUserInfo", { "email": window.datalayer_data.userID }]);
            }
        }
```

But when I read the _etmc object through the console, I can see the orgId number set correctly, but in the userinfo object, the email is is set to undefined.

I tried to use some console.log to make sure the data is there and that the _etmc object exists and the function push exists, and all of them return the correct value, I get the user id correctly and the _etmc object exists and has the push function ready. I don't know what else to try, so I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Not sure this is really the forum or there's enough info in your post to work with, but SetUserInfo should be called before TrackPageView... The pixel's already been rendered before you've told _etmc who the user is.